# Add phone number to search functionality in woocommerce orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, orders

I am using WooCommerce and I need some help. How to extend search functionality to the customer phone number in the admin WooCommerce orders list?

This is my code actually.

```
function woocommerce_shop_order_search_custom_keys( $search_fields ) {
    $search_fields[] = '_order_number';
    $search_fields[] = '_billing_phone';
    $search_fields[] = '_billing_id';
    return $search_fields;

}
```

**But is not working**

---

**EDIT:** I have also tried to add this to my code without any success:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_custom_keys' );
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? On some hooks ?
This functions alone does not gives any idea.

Comment: yes , i don't have idea how can i call the how to search

Comment: just now i added the line

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_custom_keys' );
 this way i called

Comment: but not working

Comment: ok i will try please tell me parameter name like EX:http://localhost:8080/iconnect/public/api/v1/order?tel=9629801174

Comment: http://localhost:8080/iconnect/public/api/v1/order?search=testdata&tel=9629801174

Comment: this is my web services url :http://localhost:8080/iconnect/public/api/v1/order?_billing_phone=9629801174

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to get the billing phone as in the orders list search field within a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields`** filter hook is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'billing_phone_search_fields', 10, 1 );
function billing_phone_search_fields( $meta_keys ){
    $meta_keys[] = '_billing_phone';
    return $meta_keys;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce 3+ and works.

Comment: I have applied your coed but i have doubt when i search phone the parameter name ? this is my web services URL: http://localhost:8080/iconnect/public/api/v1/order?_billing_phone=9629801174