# Allow search using billing email in WooCommerce Admin Orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

Based on [Add columns to admin orders list in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446617/add-columns-to-admin-orders-list-in-woocommerce) answer code, I was able to add 3 custom columns to Admin Orders list:

- billing email,
- billing phone,
- payment method title.

My Code:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_custom_columns_to_admin_orders', 20);
function add_custom_columns_to_admin_orders( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array();
    foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_info ) {
        $new_columns[ $column_name ] = $column_info;

        if ( 'order_total' === $column_name ) {
            $new_columns['order_email'] = __( 'Email Address', 'my-textdomain' );
            $new_columns['order_customers_phone'] = __( 'Customers Phone', 'my-textdomain' );
            $new_columns['order_payment'] = __( 'Payment Method', 'my-textdomain' );
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}


add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'custom_columns_content_in_admin_orders' );
function custom_columns_content_in_admin_orders( $column ) {
    global $post, $the_order;
    if ( 'order_email' === $column ) {
        if ( $the_order->has_status( array('completed') ) ) {
            $email_address = $the_order->get_billing_email();
            echo '<span class="order_complete"> '.$email_address.' </span>';
        } else {
            echo '<span class="order_not_complete">This Order is Not Completed!</span>';
        }
    }
    
    if ( 'order_customers_phone' === $column ) {
        echo '<label for="billing_phone" class="label-billing-email">Customer Phone Number:  </label>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="billing_phone" value="' . $the_order->get_billing_phone() . '" readonly />';
    }
    
    if ( 'order_payment' === $column ) {
        echo $the_order->get_payment_method_title();
    }
}
```

How to use the search field with the billing email, or the billing phone, or the payment method title?

[image]

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I would appreciate it if you could tell me what exactly my-textdomain is used for in the first function?

Comment: "my-textdomain" is to be replaced with the related plugin text domain slug like for example "woocommerce". It is used for string translations in multilingual websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854571/add-phone-number-to-search-functionality-in-woocommerce-orders-list/45855245#45855245), the following will make Admin Orders searchable via:

- the billing email,
- the billing phone,
- or the payment method title.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'extending_admin_orders_search_field', 10, 1 );
function extending_admin_orders_search_field( $meta_keys ){
    $meta_keys[] = '_billing_email';
    $meta_keys[] = '_billing_phone';
    $meta_keys[] = '_payment_method_title';

    return $meta_keys;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: It was wonderful as always.
If, for example, in this condition, the code `if ( 'order_email' === $column )` has displayed the email as md5, how should it be handled for searching? (What meta keys should I put? Because the email is not normal and the email is md5!)
`$meta_keys[] = '_billing_email';
$meta_keys[] = '_billing_phone';
$meta_keys[] = '_payment_method_title';`

Comment: I mostly want to know how to search for custom columns like this link in my question.
[ADDING COLUMNS IN WOOCOMMERCE ADMIN ORDERS LIST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36453587/21919676)

Comment: You will use `$meta_keys[] = '_the_meta_key1';` and  `$meta_keys[] = '_the_meta_key2';`

Comment: What values do metakeys hook on? (on the class or variable name or... for example, in my question, `$meta_keys[] = '_payment_method_title';` where does the `_payment_method_title` value come from?)

Comment: It is possible to put a specific name for each column I create, for example (album name, music name, etc.) and filter the search based on these names.

Comment: Admin orders search is made on database, so you can only use existing metadata located in wp_postmeta table for orders to perform a search on the displayed orders, when using my code answer. That said, you can always add some custom metadata on order creation, to extend the search, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have mentioned a very good point.
Now if the email value `$email_address = $the_order->get_billing_email();` Displayed as md5 => `md5($email_address )` This email value is converted to `md5` only when displayed and the same email value is stored in the database `without md5`. Now how can I call the `md5` value of the email by search? That is, how to search the value of the email `md5`?

What meta key should I use? `$meta_keys[] = '_billing_email';` => `$meta_keys[] = md5('_billing_email');`

Comment: Here, md5 is just an example, and more things may have been done on the email, for example, @ was removed, or other values were added to the email, or anything else, I just want to know the procedure.

I don't know if I was able to convey my meaning correctly or not?

Comment: *"That said, you can always **add some custom metadata on order creation**, to extend the search, for example.*"…

Comment: I created my question as a new question on the site:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77206771/i-want-to-add-a-custom-metadata-to-the-woocommerce-admin-order-page-search